# How to copy all documents from one collection to other in Firestore -Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am in a situation where when a users makes a payment, his cart products Stored in Firestore collection  ***(CartProducts)*** should be moved to new collection Called ***SuccessFullOrders*** .

***So my Basic Question is how to move all documents from one collection to Firestore other Collection in Flutter***

I don't Know how to write code for this in flutter.Thanks for your Answers

Here's  my Code

```
void _onPressed()async {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
  print(user.uid);
  firestorInstance.collection("users").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
      firestorInstance.collection("users").document(user.uid).collection("CartProducts").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {

          //what to write here so that new documents would be created in other collection 

          print(result.data);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: If you can share your code then we will be able to provide answer to it more precisely

Comment: I  edited my question and provided code.Thanks for your help♥

Comment: Check my editted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there's no way to copy a collection into another provided by `firebase` officially. And, for sure, you can iterate over your previous collection & create new documents in the other.

In your case you should be doing something like:

```dart
userFirebaseInstance
    .collection(NewCollection)
    .document()
    .setData(YourDataHere)
```

Comment: But main problem for me is that i don't know what to write in setData(YourDataHere),So that it copy all documents to new one.Please Provide an example

Comment: Simply, `result.data` if it's your data.

Comment: Thanks my friend 

Comment: Sorry i know this post in kinda old but then how can i delete the old documents